# rally synchronize lookback and alm

Tags: synchronization, rally, alm, lookbackapi

Is there any way to manually trigger a sync between lookback and alm. I just was running some lookback queries and the ETLDate was 3.8 hours out of sync. That seems like a pretty long time.

If it is notyou could throttle the requests to a maximum of 1 per every 30 minutes or something depending on how expensive it would be to sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to manually trigger a sync between Lookback and ALM. They normally happen automatically and very frequently (on the order of minutes) but, due to some recent infrastructure changes, Lookback is experiencing a somewhat longer delay in syncing with ALM for the past few weeks (on the order of hours). We are aware of the issue and working on resolving it but it may take a bit longer before Lookback sync frequency is back to its usual timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

Igor is right, there's no way to trigger a sync.  We've deployed some fixes recently that should alleviate the lag for your subscription.  Can you try your queries again and see if you are still seeing any issues?

Comment: when i checked this morning there was only a 5 minute lag. so it appears to be fixed. Thanks!